# How to run clojure program from terminal

Tags: clojure

I have just begun learning clojure and I'm using the Textmate editor for writing the scripts. However, I am not able to figure out how to run it from the terminal. Like I type the clj filename.clj command but nothing happens. Do I need to include the function name also somewhere because I have a function that takes a number as an argument.

Here is my code that I want to run from the terminal:

```
(defn next-collatz-num [n]


(if (even? n)
    (quot n 2)
    (inc (* n 3))))

(defn collatz [n]
  (take-while #(< 1 %)(iterate next-collatz-num n)))

(defn max-count-collatz [n]
  (when (> n 0)
    (first
      (reduce
        #(if (> (last %1)(last %2)) %1 %2)
          [1 1] (map #(list % (count (collatz %))) (range 1 (inc n)))))))

(max-count-collatz 999999)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clojure has a much more interactive environment than just running a whole script at the terminal command prompt.

TL;DR, install [leiningen](http://leiningen.org/), create a `project.clj`, then run `lean repl`.

If you don't want to create a `project.clj`, or if you're curious how to do it the hard way, read on...

You can start a Clojure read-eval-print-loop (REPL) interactive prompt with

```
java -cp clojure-1.6.0.jar clojure.main
```

(download the latest Clojure jar [here](http://clojure.org/downloads)).

Once you're in the REPL, load the code file:

```
(load-file "my-script.clj")
```

Now, you can call the function directly:

```
(max-count-collatz 5)
```

If it doesn't work as you'd expect, change the code, save and reload it in the REPL:

```
(require 'my-script :reload-all)
```

Comment: I don't understand the statement "Once you are in the REPL". How?

Comment: @EricaMaine, use the first line (`java -cp clojure-1.6.0.jar clojure.main`) at the terminal to launch the Clojure REPL.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/main

This is what I get when I use that line.

Comment: @EricaMaine this assumes clojure-1.6.0.jar is in the current working directory. If it's not, adjust the path to clojure-1.6.0.jar accordingly. See http://clojure.org/getting_started for more details.

Comment: The reload all command doesn't work.It gives this error : FileNotFoundException Could not locate my_script__init.class or my_script.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)

Comment: @EricaMaine you need to modify the namespace `'my-script` to match the name of the file containing your script.

Comment: I am doing that only. I just wrote "my-script" for reference. But, it's still failing giving me the above mentioned error.

Comment: It's best to Install [leiningen](http://leiningen.org/). Then just run `lein repl`

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to run individual Clojure files using Clojure.jar, one of the best things about Clojure is the [`leiningen`](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) dependency manager and build tool. Creating a project is easy, and for anything more than a single file with no external dependencies, it is a huge improvement over using java and Clojure.jar directly.

Comment: Hi, in my code in the question, when I type (collatz 7), the result that comes is (7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2), but it should actually be (7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1). Why is it missing the 1 at the end?

Comment: that's because you call `(take-while #(< 1 %) ...)` - perhaps you want `pos?` or `(complement zero?)` or `#(> % 1)`

Comment: Hi, I was trying to work with namespaces this time in my clojure code, using ns. So, I have my jar file in the Downloads directory, I created a folder "poker" in the Downloads directory. Inside the "poker folder, I created two clojure files that are dependent on each other, so I also put my jar file inside the poker folder. Now, when I did:
java -cp clojure-1.6.0.jar clojure.main
It gave me "Permission denied". Why is that?